# Grouping database values in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a successful query that's building a select list but it's adding each location_name value as a label with it's corresponding display_name, as opposed to just one location label with each corresponding display

My query:

```
$getDisplayByLocation = "
SELECT l.id as locationID, location_name, d.id as displayID, display_name
from locations l
inner join displays d
    on l.id = d.location_id;
";

$displayLocation = $mysqlConn->query($getDisplayByLocation);
```

returns

```
locationID  |  location_name  |  displayID  |  display_name 
    4             building4         1              Room One
    4             building4         2              Room Two
    1             building1         3              Room One
    1             building1         4              Room Two
```

But my list builds with each building

```
building4
->Room One
building4
->Room Two
building1
->Room One
building1
->Room Two
```

instead of

```
building4
->Room One
->Room Two
building1
->Room One
->Room Two
```

My select list

```
<select name="displayId" class="form-control" id="areaSelect">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Select one...</option>
        <?php foreach($displayLocation as $displayLoc): ?>
            <optgroup label="<?php echo $displayLoc['location_name']?>">
            <option value="<?php echo $displayLoc['displayID']?>"><?php echo $displayLoc['display_name']?></option>
        <?php endforeach?>
</select>
```

Comment: Here's a simple example of array transformation... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50680400/how-to-group-a-specific-field-in-array/50685909#50685909